# Tizen Wearable Native Application: How do we dump a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm implementing a *Tizen Wearable Hybrid Application* (Web UI + Native Service). Native Service uses the [SQLite Database](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/data-storage-and-management/sqlite-database-engine) for record maintenance. **I need to export a *SQLite dump file* of the database in `csv` format to share that with the Web UI.** Unfortunately I couldn't find anything with the web search. Someone please guide me **how can I create a dump file from SQLite in Tizen Wearable Native Application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1. Converting db files to csv file

```
1) Copy db files to res
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/native-application-development/how-copy-sqlite-data.db-file-application-runtime?langredirect=1#comment-25969

2) Converting db files to csv file
https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-export-data-from-table-to-csv-file
```

Method 2. Coding read data and write them to csv file directly
   [Exporting the sqlite3 table into file using "C" execute API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289510/exporting-the-sqlite3-table-into-file-using-c-execute-api)

Comment: The conversion code is not working in `Tizen` but still it helped a lot.. Thanks a lot for showing me the way to the _actual_ solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is to implement [datacontrol provider](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/data-control) functionality in your native service application and [datacontrol consumer](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/data-control) functionality in your UI Web application.

Provider can implement SQL data provisioning and update, consumer can then use data provided using [Web API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/datacontrol.html).

Comment: Many thanks for the response, that makes sense. Let me try this :)

Comment: I need the data **in a csv file** which can be ultimately sent to the Server. I don't see this functionality available in the API. I've updated my question now. I've implemented the Message Port Communication between the two Applications and I'm already able to share the data between the two apps through messages.